# Titanium + ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, uiwebview, cross-platform, titanium-mobile

I want to wrap entire website that has been created in html code in Titanium webview to create application for Ipad. This particular website contains ember.js code as well as other kinds of js too. I have successfully loaded index.html in webview. But I can see nothing more than a blank webview more surprisingly no error is being displayed in Titanium Console.                  I added simple html content to same index.html file and output of same is being displayed on webview. But for rest of html content in index.htmlsomething like following has been written
`<script type='text/x-handlebars' id="application">` 
Can any one help on this issue ? or has tried something like this previously. Any guidance or help regarding this would be highly appreciated. Or any way using which we could trace where html page throws error

Comment: Yes i am also not able to find anything on the same.Please help on this topic.Thank you.

Comment: What errors did you get? What Titanium SDK was this reproduced on? Any sample code to help troubleshooting?

Other than that, this was taken from the Apple Review Guidelines: 

2.12 Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected